# I have troubles understanding how does the floor function works

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let me explain, floor function works fine, but when you drag it into real analysis, it behaves indeed strangely.

So if we take a derivative it is zero (no doubts, but it's undefined in integers). But if we integrate zero, we don't get floor(x).

Other thing is intgreation. I have made a function (**$F(x) = floor(x)-\frac12(floor(x)^2)$**). It does count area under the graph, but it is useless for integration by parts and the derivative does not equal floor(x).

I think the answer is connected to Fourier transformation, if anybody could help, I would be very thankful.

Comment: If you want the integral of the derivative to get you back to the original function ($\pm$ a constant) you need to start with a differentiable function.

Comment: you can't apply the theorems (fundamental theorem of calculus, integration by parts etc) if their hypotheses are not satisfied.  So, there's no surprise here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the field of signal processing, differentiation of step functions like `floor` are handled using the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

$$\frac{d}{dx} \lfloor x \rfloor = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \delta(x-n)$$

δ is not a function in the classical sense, but a "distribution" defined by the property that

$$\int_a^b \delta(x) dx = \begin{cases}1 & \text{if } 0 \in [a, b]\\0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

It has a Fourier transform of 1.